# Can I find the close date of the first opportunity on an account with a formula?

Tags: apex, formula-field

At my company, we define the "launch date" as the close date of the first opportunity that belongs to an Account. So if an Account has 20 Opportunities, we find the first one, and use that close date as our launch date. Then we need to store that on the account.

I currently have some Apex that does this:

```
Account acc = [ SELECT Id, Name, Industry__c, LaunchDate__c from Account where Account.Id = :opp.AccountId  ]; 

Opportunity first_opp = [ SELECT Id, Name, CloseDate, AccountId,    StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :opp.AccountId and     StageName = 'Closed Done' ORDER BY closedate limit 1 ];

acc.LaunchDate__c = first_opp.CloseDate; 

update acc;
```

I'm curious if there is any way to convert this to a formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible via Roll up summary field on Account object.
Select roll up type as "Min" and field to aggregate as "Close Date"
You can choose filter criteria as you want for example in you case you can put status ="Closed Done" as a filter criteria.

[image]

Comment: How do I connect this to the Opportunities?

Comment: @charlottesville That's why I included the dropdown on my own answer.

Comment: Click on new field and choose roll up. There choose the summarized object as Opportunities.

Answer (score 3):

Formulas can't work on child records. However, you can create a Rollup Summary field to automatically calculate the earliest date:

[image: Earliest Close Date Rollup Summary Field]

Comment: I am impressed, I had same thought like great Mr fox. Great answer